# Java to C Communication

Tags: java, c, ipc

I have a embedded device which has the Front End GUI in JAVA.
Back end module in C Language.

I already using JNI interface for the communication between JAVA & C.

But i think it is heavy weight. So can You Guys, Please suggest other ways/Methods/Techniques which is available ?

Comment: It's the JNI way or the highway.

Comment: `But i think it is heavy weight` - Is it just your assumption or is there any concrete proof it's being heavy? I wrote a bunch of JNI application and none of them was heavy nor slow.

Comment: please suggest me, if any other options available other than JNI interface ?

Comment: Please indicate what specific problems you are having with JNI so that proper suggestions can be made. "heavy weight" is neither specific enough nor conclusive.

Comment: No experience, but there is **Java Native Access (JNA)**

Comment: So you say socket communication may be expensive? Aren't all communication methods actually based on the most primitive socket communication?

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for some wort of library ... then: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. If not ... I agree with all the other comments: what makes you think that JNI is "too slow" for you?!

Comment: Maybe not "is heavyweight", but You lost resources? Show code. Tell way of deduction, to conclusion "is heavyweight" Hard to imagine "better new interface" if not sure, "old" is used properly

Comment: @BhaskaraLogesh I'm not really expert in that but i think you can use a bus IPC mechanism to communicate between your processes to request methods (Functions) or send signals. D-Bus wire protocol is one great bus heavily used in modern Linux distributions. For instance, all major Desktop Environments (GNOME, KDE, XFCE) are actually using it to process different events. Java have a binding of the D-Bus library and C also has a high level wrapper library (Glib) to connect using D-Bus bus daemon. I think Google may give you more [D-Bus](https://dbus.freedesktop.org).

Comment: [Another good Wiki](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/D-Bus)